# AngularJS - Unable to inject ngStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use `$localStorage` in a service. I am including the `ngStorage` cdn in the head section of `index.html`.

```
<script src="Vendor/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="Vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="Vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="Vendor/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngStorage/0.3.6/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
```

`savePreferenceService.js`

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var savePreferenceService = function ($localStorage) {

        this.selectedPreferences = function (selectedLang, converse, selectedNumber) {
            $localStorage.selectedLang = selectedLang;
            $localStorage.converse = converse;
            $localStorage.selectedNumber = selectedNumber;

            console.log($localStorage.selectedLang);
            console.log($localStorage.converse);
            console.log($localStorage.selectedNumber);
        }

        this.getPreferences = function () {
               return this.userPreferences = {
                selectedLang : '',

                converse : {
                    state: 'on'
                 },

                selectedNumber : 0
            }
        }

        this.selectedPreferences = function (selectedLang, converse, selectedNumber) {
            this.selectedLang = selectedLang;
            this.converse = converse;
            this.selectedNumber = selectedNumber;

            console.log(this.selectedLang);
            console.log(this.converse);
            console.log(this.selectedNumber);
        }
  };    

      angular.module('iisEmail', ['ngStorage'])
        .service ('savePreferenceService', ['$localStorage', savePreferenceService]);
}());
```

I don't understand why I am getting `ng:areq` error. I think I am not injecting ngStorage correctly. Does anyone have ideas on what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I removed the `ngStorage` dependency from the service and added it to `main.js`. Doing this resolved the error I was having. I think this error was being caused because I wasn't injecting the dependency in my `main.js` where the module `iisEmail` was defined.

`savePreferenceService`

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var savePreferenceService = function ($localStorage) {

        this.selectedPreferences = function (selectedLang, converse, selectedNumber) {
           /* $localStorage.selectedLang = selectedLang;
            $localStorage.converse = converse;
            $localStorage.selectedNumber = selectedNumber;

            console.log($localStorage.selectedLang);
            console.log($localStorage.converse);
            console.log($localStorage.selectedNumber);*/
        }

        this.getPreferences = function () {
               return this.userPreferences = {
                selectedLang : '',

                converse : {
                    state: 'on'
                 },

                selectedNumber : 0
            }
        }

        this.selectedPreferences = function (selectedLang, converse, selectedNumber) {
            this.selectedLang = selectedLang;
            this.converse = converse;
            this.selectedNumber = selectedNumber;

            console.log(this.selectedLang);
            console.log(this.converse);
            console.log(this.selectedNumber);
        }
  };    

      angular.module('iisEmail')
        .service ('savePreferenceService', ['$localStorage', savePreferenceService]);
}());
```

`main.js`

```
var app = angular.module("iisEmail",['ui.router', 'ngStorage']);

app.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
        var primary = {
            name:"primary",
            url:"/",
            templateUrl:"app/partials/emailView.html"
            //controller:"emailViewCtrl"
        };
        var settings ={
            name:"settings",
            url:"/",
            templateUrl:"app/partials/settings.html"
            //controller:"emailViewCtrl"
        };
        $stateProvider.state('default',primary);
        $stateProvider.state('settings',settings);
    }]);
```

Comment: I have created a jsFiddle for your provided code and it runs without errors https://jsfiddle.net/bpjqmjma/

Comment: @Dola he must be missing some other module..error is not related to the code which is present in answer